# Programmatically open a Chrome plugin's options.html page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to open a Google Chrome plugin's options.html page via Javascript in background.html?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "options.html" });
```

*Update*

Starting with version 40, Chrome now uses a new popup options dialog from the extension management page instead of dedicated options pages (which are being deprecated).  You can still achieve the same effect with a modification to the URL.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': 'chrome://extensions/?options=' + chrome.runtime.id });
```

Comment: oh rats... that looks much cleaner XD

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Comment: @Ska You cannot use this directly in a content script.  It must be in a background script or you must use the `web_accessible_resources` option in your manifest file.

Comment: In the updated part of this answer you forgot the "url:" part. The call should be `chrome.tabs.create({ "url": "chrome://extensions/?options=" + chrome.runtime.id });`

Comment: seems even the Update is now out of date with the introduction of `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`

Comment: Yes, this is kinda deprecated with `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`!

Comment: `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()` only works for your own extension's options, not for others' (for example via the `management` permission)

Comment: The url format has changed, it is now:  `"chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/options.html"`

Answer (score 68):

There is a new method that is enabled [beginning with Chrome 42](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=430054#c36):

> [`chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage)
>
> Open your Extension's options page, if possible.
>
> The precise behavior may depend on your manifest's `options_ui` or `options_page` key, or what Chrome happens to support at the time. For example, the page may be opened in a new tab, within `chrome://extensions`, within an App, or it may just focus an open options page. It will never cause the caller page to reload.
>
> If your Extension does not declare an options page, or Chrome failed to create one for some other reason, the callback will set `lastError`.

Comment: This is correct method. people should use this way instead of chrome.tabs.create(...options.html..)

Comment: The only way that is not a dirty hack.

Comment: If this doesn't seem to work in your script, it's probably because you need to declare the function in your background.js first. Check this comment on the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192949/11060914

Answer (score 31):

Open or switch to already opened options page (instead of opening a duplicate):

```
var optionsUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('options.html');

chrome.tabs.query({url: optionsUrl}, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.length) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {active: true});
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: optionsUrl});
    }
});
```

Comment: `chrome.extension.getURL` is unneccessary.  `update` and `create` both accept URLs relative to the calling page or script.

Comment: Actually chrome.extension.getURL is necessary. [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) does not accept fragment identifiers for URLs.

It should also be noted that the Tabs permission is required since you're trying to access tab URLs.

Comment: Still useful as a shim for `openOptionsPage` until it becomes available in Firefox's WebExtensions.

Comment: It's work fine for open internal and external urls, **note:** is needed add `"tabs"` in `permissions:`, see example: `"permissions": [ "tabs" ]` +1

Comment: also do this if you want to swap to the window where the current options page is open:

`chrome.windows.update(tabs[0].windowId, {focused: true});`

Answer (score 3):

Without using the Chrome API, only the standard Web APIs, the following is possible:

```
window.open("chrome-extension://ghipmampnddcpdlppkkamoankmkmcbmh/options.html")
```

Or, to navigate from a visible page to an extension page:

```
location.href = "chrome-extension://ghipmampnddcpdlppkkamoankmkmcbmh/options.html"
```

This requires hardcoding the extension ID.

**Probably the only time this is preferable over using the Chrome API is when it's called from a non-extension context** (and not the original "from background page" scenario). However, note that a web context cannot navigate to a `chrome-extension://*` page (it will result in `about:blank`) unless it's [declared as web-accessible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

In such a scenario, one should also consider communicating with the webpage either through a content script or [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) instead.

Comment: This way you have to know extension's key. It's ambiguous. Accepted answer is better.

Comment: @szamil  I'm going to keep this answer based on the fact that it enables someone who is not the developer to open up the options page via javascript and externally to the extension.  I am not sure if that is what the original poster was intending (in fact it's quite unlikely), but this answer may be useful to someone at some time.  Not that I'm proud of this answer... I think this answer is horrible structured, but that's what the vote system is for.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Your correct.  This answer is poor in practice, but it's good for understanding the inner workings.

Comment: _"I'm going to keep this answer based on the fact that it enables someone who is not the developer to open up the options page via javascript and externally to the extension."_ Not even true anymore unless the page is listed in `web_accessible_resources` - you will get `about:blank` trying to navigate that way.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the info!  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: No-no, it makes sense, just needs more explanations - in the answer, not in the comments. If you'd like, you can mark this as community wiki answer and I'll fill in the blanks.

Comment: @Xan If you feel it has any value to future visitors, you can edit the answer if you want.  Personally I still feel after five years, that this is very sloppy and that there are or should be better ways to do it.  Unfortunately, the last time I tried my hand at chrome plugins was a long time ago (about five years :P), so my input is not going to be very reliable.

Comment: I would be more comfortable working this into shape if it was CW, which only you can enable. If you don't care much about what happens to this answer, that should be acceptable for you.

Comment: @Xan Can do.  I just don't feel like I have the appropriate knowledge in this area.  Really is should belong in CW.

Comment: You don't have to hardcode the extension url: chrome.runtime.getURL('options.html')

Comment: Hardcoding url might better for compability but pain for development stage.