# Trying to link to options page: Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: google-chrome-extension

According to [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2):

> To link to your extension's options page, use a URL like chrome://extensions?options=yourextensionid. This loads chrome://extensions then automatically opens your options page in a dialogue.
>
> ```
> <a href="chrome://extensions?options=aebdgjojlaaljcehfkjaknmlilmblnip">
>    Go to options.
> </a>
> ```

In a content script (injected into a web page), I have put such a link, but when I click it, I get the message:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions/?options=blahblahblah
```

I have checked that the identifier string is correct. I have tried adding `options.html` to `web_accessible_resources`, but to no avail. Is it possible to launch the options page from a content script at all?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can't directly link to any `chrome://` page.

Instead, you can use a click handler that calls (or delegates to your background page if it's a content script) `chrome.tabs.create({url: "..."})` which can open privileged pages.

Or better yet, there's an [upcoming API call `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage) and it will hit Stable in Chrome 42.

Comment: Better yet, don't use the new options system at all.

Comment: @DanielHerr It's going to be deprecated eventually.

Comment: Not chrome.tabs.create({ url: "options.html"})

Comment: @DanielHerr Then I don't get your comment. If you are going to rely on `chrome.tabs.create`, what difference the new system makes (w.r.t this)?

Comment: The difference? Others will use the new system, which has horrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
//from chrome 42 onward, per Xan on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782391/programmatically-open-a-chrome-plugins-options-html-page
//chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();

//until then...
var optionsUrl = "chrome://extensions/?options=" + chrome.runtime.id
chrome.tabs.query({url: optionsUrl}, function(tabs) {
  if (tabs.length) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {active: true});
  } else {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: optionsUrl});
  }
});
```