# Options page in new Firefox WebExtensions API

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way to write addon options page in new Firefox WebExtensions API?

For example Google Chrome supports manifest key ["options_page"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) 
I searched through documentation and wiki but can't find anything on this point.

Comment: You need to explain what you want from an "options page" in terms of UI/behavior

Comment: @Xan, options page is a way to allow users to customize the behavior of extension. Options page can be declared in manifest.json. The page itself is html+js to persist the addon's options.

Comment: And how the user would discover/open it? (I know full well how it works in Chrome, but I'm trying to coax out of you which parts you want in FF)

Comment: @Xan, Firefox WebExtensions are designed to be compatible with Chrome extensions as far as possible, extensions written for Chrome browser should run on Firefox with minimal changes. As far as I understand when WebExtensions are gonna be released all firefox addons should be reimplemented using new approach. It would be very nice to have the same "options page" stuff but I can't find anything on that in docs [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities)

Comment: My point being, there are many UI things that may not translate directly to Firefox with respect to option pages. Seems like it's not currently supported as-is, but if you can list features you want from it (preferably by use cases), someone can propose a workaround.

Comment: I'm trying to investigate the required effort of porting existing Google Chrome extension to Firefox WebExtensions. I've found all relevant APIs  that are used in Chrome addon except "options_page" stuff. Also there is nothing about options_page in the scope of [First release of Web Extensions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214433).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is out of date as WebExtension support expands.

See [Implement a settings page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page) on MDN (and please upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131597/934239) for providing this link first).

---

It does not seem like `"options_page"` manifest key is supported as of now.

Its main use is providing UI discoverability of the options page; a link to it in the extension list, for instance.

If you're porting an existing extension, you'll need to add some other UI in your extension to open the page (e.g. a link in the popup, if the extension has one). You can simply open it with `chrome.tabs.create` like you would open any page and it will work identically.

A little caveat: if the extension uses [OptionsV2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2)-provided CSS styling, you'll need to compensate for its absence.

Another caveat: the `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()` function is not available in Firefox and should be replaced by a [shim using `chrome.tabs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16130739/934239).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `options_ui` key in your `manifest.json`. There is nice guide on MDN on how to do this - [Implement a settings page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page).

Answer (score 2):

Both "options_page" and "options_ui" will be implemented in Firefox WebExtensions!

Here is the link for tracking progress http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/#options