# Is there a URL that I can use to programmatically navigate to a WebExtensions options screen?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

In a Chrome extension I can do:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'chrome://extensions/?options=' + chrome.runtime.id });
```

Is there some similar action that I can do in a Firefox WebExtensions add-on to navigate to the options screen for my add-on?

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the options page for the extension which is executing the `tabs.create()`, or are you trying to open some other extension's option page? In other words, are you looking for some way to generically navigate to the options page for any add-on as long as you have it's add-on ID? The code you are using implies that you are wanting to navigate to the options page for the current add-on. Is there a reason that you are not using `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`, which is the normal way you open the options page in Chrome, and also works in Firefox?

Comment: Sigh. Because I didn't know about it. That API wasn't available when I wrote my original Chrome extension (in 2014) and so I used the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782391/programmatically-open-a-chrome-plugins-options-html-page). Then when I wanted to port the extension to Firefox, a Google for "firefox add-on options URL" and variants (understandably) didn't lead me to that API either. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Not a problem, we all learn all the time. I'm glad you were able to get your problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `runtime.openOptionsPage()` function after defining the options page in the manifest. It will return a promise for the creation of the options page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage