# How to call browser extension from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, protractor

I am using Protractor to test Angular JS content of an application.
As part of my automation scripts, i have to launch a application url and then call browser extension .

On clicking the browser extension - i am getting this URL

"chrome-extension://glfffgjbfebdaehgdcaachlfcpkggbbc/html/options.html#"

I have tried some solutions stated on google forums like, but the extension from automation script is getting launched.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getURL

[Programmatically open a Chrome plugin's options.html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782391/programmatically-open-a-chrome-plugins-options-html-page)

Due to security purposes, i am not sharing the code. I request someone to advise me on how to achieve this task. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Browser extensions run isolated to the other components for security reasons. They can only access the webpage not the other way around. That is also very limited. The variables in console environment of a page cannot be accessed by the extension and so the other way around.

You can try [web-accessible-resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) if you own the extension otherwise not much you can do.