# How can I open my options.html? Currently I get Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: "chrome-extension://kgllckjehjabihppilipeagjojdmlfch/options.html"
    });
}
```

Is what I found should work. I also tried the same with `url: "options.html"`. But when the code is running, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (myscript.js:70)

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs API. See documentation for chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage instead.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use chrome.tabs.create in a content script. This API is only available for background scripts. Instead, use window.open to create new tabs from within a content script.

```
// Regular webpage; works
window.open("https://google.com");
// Privileged URL; is redirected to about:blank
window.open("chrome-extension://kgllckjehjabihppilipeagjojdmlfch/options.html");
```

For the options page, this does **not** work since it uses the chrome-extension protocol, which Firefox does not support using window.open.

This is the way I open my options page in a **background** script:

```
chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
```

If you need to call it in a **content script**, use messaging: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

Example:

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case "openOptionsPage":
            openOptionsPage();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});

function openOptionsPage(){
    chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
}
```

content_script.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"action": "openOptionsPage"});
```

Comment: Using the window.open method it works, but opens about:blank. Any idea why this might be?

Edit: I have tabs permission granted

Comment: It probably doesn't recognise the chrome-extension protocol this way, or denies the opening. You might see a warning message in your browser console. I've added example code to my answer about the other approach with message passing.